# Compiling Adobe Air Mobile App with Air 3.9 and Greater in Flashbuilder 4.7

Tags: air, flash-builder

Ok here is the background, I created an Adobe Air mobile app with Flash Builder 4.7 and compiled it with Flex 4.9.1 and Air 3.7.. Worked great until Android 4.4 rolled out. Now the app crashes on opening.

I used the Apache Flex Installer and downloaded Flex 4.12.1 and AIR 13. I set the project property to use this Flex SDK. When I try and export a release build, I get the following error:

aapt tool failed: invalid resource directory C:\Users\Me\Appdata\Local\Temp......\captive_runtime_res/drawable-xxhdpi

So I tried to use AIR 3.9 because xxhdpi was first supported in this version of Adobe Air, but I get the same error.

I have tried using the stock aapt in the Android Tools API 19 and still get the same error.
Does anyone have any suggestions? I hope this is enough information.

Update: I uninstalled and Reinstalled Flash Builder 4.7 for a Clean Install.. Still the same results..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I believe this is specific error on my Windows 7 64bit Dev computer.  I installed Flash Builder on my Mac and installed the SDKs. I compiled with no problems.